# Add Salesforce Lead record with file attachment

Tags: plugins, plugin-freeform, freeform, integration, plugin-expressforms

Can anyone know if it is possible to upload a file to the SalesForce service using the Freeform, Express form or another plugin...? (i.e. need to add Lead record with file attachment) Thanks

Comment: Sad to see there is no answer on this one yet. I was looking for the same.

Comment: I recommend getting in touch with the developer if you haven't already.